# syntax error near unexpected token while use subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, fabric

This design makes me cry,code below,please help

```
def runbatch(CMD,HOST):
    print CMD
    print HOST
    for host in HOST:
        env.host_string=host
        print CMD
        print env.host_string
        print "Execute command : \"%s\" at Host : %s" %(CMD,host)
        print "-------------------------------------------------"
        p=subprocess.Popen("run('ls')",shell=True,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = p.communicate()
        print output
```

error shows

*(None, "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `'ls''\n/bin/sh: -c: line 0:`run('ls')'\n")*

Comment: are you trying to run the command `ls` from your python script? if so, try `p=subprocess.Popen("ls",shell=True)`. That should list all the files in your current into stdout.

Comment: ls returns ok but i need to use fabric run command to list remote hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen()` runs a bash command on your **local machine**. What `fabric` has to offer is a way to enter a command on *local machine* which got sent to and run on a *remote machine*. To this end, you need a `fabfile.py` (for now, you need to name it precisely `fabfile.py`) where you store the fabric `fabric.api.run()` command, which actually is a Python command and not a bash command. The argument of `fabric.api.run()` is a bash command that runs on the *remote machine*. E.g. of a `fabfile.py`

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import env
def runcommand():
    run(env.my_command)
```

Using this example, you could activate this remote call by using command line `fab --set my_command=some_bash_command -H remote_host_ip runcommand`. This string is the string you should pass to `subprocess.Popen()` in your script. E.g. let's call your script `stackoverflow.py` that takes in a command line argument the bash function to be executed on the *remote machine*

```
import subprocess
import sys

p=subprocess.Popen("fab --set my_command="+sys.argv[1]+" -H localhost runcommand",shell=True,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate()
print output
```

Sample run:

```
Chip chip@ 12:10:58@ ~: python stackoverflow.py ls
[localhost] Executing task 'runcommand'
[localhost] run: ls
[localhost] out: AllArms.py             fines
[localhost] out: Applications               github
[localhost] out: Box Sync               grades_assgn1
[localhost] out: DFExperiment               heuristic.py
[localhost] out: Desktop                    honour-project-in-thompson-sampling
[localhost] out: Documents              jags_bin
[localhost] out: Downloads              latemath
[localhost] out: Dropbox                    launchall.sh
[localhost] out: FIT3080                    launcher
[localhost] out: GaussianExperiments            launchucb.sh
[localhost] out: GoogleDrive                minuteSep5
[localhost] out: HierarchicalStan.py            minutes22aug
[localhost] out: IMG_6169.JPG               model1.pkl
[localhost] out: Library                    mydata
[localhost] out: Monarch                    notes15Aug2016
[localhost] out: Movies                 notesSep12
[localhost] out: Music                  old-honour
[localhost] out: PTSTuneBeta                oracle.R
[localhost] out: Pictures               paper
[localhost] out: Public                 parallelExperiments
[localhost] out: Samsung                    people_to_mark_first
[localhost] out: WindowFrame.class          rezaPhone
[localhost] out: WindowFrame.java           spike.py
[localhost] out: a.out                  stackoverflow.class
[localhost] out: aaai.tar.gz                stackoverflow.cpp
[localhost] out: all_experiments                stackoverflow.java
[localhost] out: api4.csv               stackoverflow.py
[localhost] out: atlas                  test
[localhost] out: boostlib               test.py
[localhost] out: codes_and_data.tar.gz          test.txt
[localhost] out: eclipse                    test1.html
[localhost] out: emo                    test2.html
[localhost] out: experimentlist             testlib.py
[localhost] out: fabfile.py             testlib.pyc
[localhost] out: fabfile.pyc                uselib.py
[localhost] out: file1                  uselib.pyc
[localhost] out: file2
[localhost] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from localhost... done.
(None, "[localhost] Login password for 'hiennguyen': \n")
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: When calling `fab` this way, you might have to:

1. Enable `ssh` access to your *remote machine*. In this case, the *remote machine* is just `localhost`
2. Sometimes, the *remote host* requires you to enter password and you **will not** be prompted to enter password (this is the case on my machine). If you wait for awhile and see nothing, you might want to enter the password then hit ENTER.